# How to get xpath of an image that I found earlier using its class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

So, I have an image with HTML class 'anImage'. This image has XPath of:

```
.//*[@id='mainBody']/table/tbody/tr[variable]/td[2]/img
```

the `variable` changes every time I see the website, it can be 4, it can be 7 etc.

Next to that image I have an image that I want to click, it has an xpath of:

```
.//*[@id='mainBody']/table/tbody/tr[variable]/td[7]/a/img
```

So my idea is:

1. Find the first image using it's class
2. Get its xpath
3. Extract the variable out of its xpath
4. Find the other element using the variable and the rest of the xpath

Now: how do I get the xpath of the first element?

I'm using python and selenium if someone hadn't noticed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a *single XPath expression*:

```
.//*[@id='mainBody']/table/tbody/tr[td[2]/img[contains(@class, 'anImage')]]/td[7]/a/img
```

The `tr[td[2]/img[contains(@class, 'anImage')]]` part is the key one - basically, we locate the row containing the image with a class `anImage` in the second `td`. Then, in that located row, we are getting the `img` tag in `a` tag in the 7th `td` element.

Comment: I don't really know much about xpaths, I just find them with FirePath then use them in my code to locate them. Can you help me with implementing it in Python using Selenium?

Right now I only have 

    match = browser.find_element_by_class_name('anImage')

Comment: @ca1ek just use `find_element_by_xpath()` method instead.

Comment: Thank you man. But, for the future: how did you construct this xpath, any tutorial on the webs?

Comment: @ca1ek you cannot auto-generate an XPath like this, it is just knowing the syntax and applying some coffee and logic. Happy seleniuming!